# 2 и более свойства CSS в JS

Tags: javascript

Как передать несколько свойств CSS в JS. Нужна запятая или что? Я запутался =(

В данном случае как правильно прописать несколько свойств **transition: 1s ease-in в JS.**

**И каким образом обнулить несколько свойств в JS, то есть 1-свойство =1s и второе = ease-in?**

```js
let block = document.querySelector(".block");

block.style.transition = '' // Как правильно написать 1s ease-in?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все прописывается так же как и в CSS, все правила для запятых и пробелов одинаковые.
Свойство transition можно задать как в одной строке так и частями (transition-property, transition-duration, transition-timing-function, transition-delay).

Единственная разница в тому, что символ - в сите заменяется на большую букву. Например вместо transition-duration с css надо писать transitionDuration в js

```js
document.body.style.height = '100vh';
document.body.style.transition = 'background 1s linear';
document.body.style.background = 'rgb(81, 190, 255) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% content-box';
setTimeout(() => document.body.style.background = 'rgb(81, 190, 255) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% content-box');
setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.style.background = 'red';
  document.body.style.transitionDuration = '5s';
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое =)